# Is it possible to dereference CSS file in HTML

Tags: html, css

I wonder is it possible to dereference a CSS file referenced earlier in the HTMl page.

I'm asking because I'm responsible for part of the page, the framework rendering the whole page references some CSS file in the format of 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=XXX.css>`
And this CSS file is overwriting my CSS file, so I wonder if I can dereference it or is there any other suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, but put your css after the other is referenced. So it will override the other one.

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire css ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to remove that file try putting more specific CSS rules:

```
[parent.css]
a {
    color: red;
}

[your_file.css]
body a {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Won't help if we're applying 'themes' such as winter theme, spring theme, fall theme, etc., but the layout is the same.

Comment: @cst1992 It will work. Apply global theme for body, like `.spring` and apply this theme for all your custom styles. Common styles will not have this prefixed class. I suggest using LESS compiler, too

Answer (score 1):

CSS always applies on entire document.

The way you can do for only one div is just define a unique id or class to your div you want to write css for.

```
<div class="main_div" id="myCss">
  //further content like h1, div, ul, li
</div>
```

And now when you write css just inherit all the css like this

```
#myCss h1{
  // mycss
}
#myCss ul li{
  // mycss
}
```

This way css will be applied only on your div.